# android avd cursor pointer image

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, mouse-cursor

I am trying to make a quick instructional video of my new app and I want to use a custom cursor in the shape of a finger in the avd so that the video makes sense to my users.  I can get a custom cursor to work in windows with no problems however the android avd uses a custom black cursor with a white outline that will not be replaced by my custom windows cursor.  Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

for editing the cursor image we have to edit the framework-res.apk file with the new cursor image using smali.jar and baksmali.jar files and we have to push it to the device again